# Linux command to get the user and its group in a specific output for Ansible

Tags: linux, shell, ansible

I have the following output:

```
dante
Last password change                    : Aug 18, 2017
Password expires                    : never
Password inactive                   : never
Account expires                     : never
Minimum number of days between password change      : 0
Maximum number of days between password change      : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires   : 7
Linux shell                                         : /bin/bash

marion
Last password change                    : Aug 28, 2017
Password expires                    : never
Password inactive                   : never
Account expires                     : never
Minimum number of days between password change      : 0
Maximum number of days between password change      : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires   : 7
Linux shell                                         : /bin/bash
```

This output is done with the following command:

```
cat /etc/passwd | xargs -n1 -I{} bash -c 'a=`echo "{}" | cut -f1 -d:`; echo -e "\n$a"; chage -l $a; echo -e "Linux shell\t: " `echo "{}" | cut -f7 -d:`' >> users-list.log
```

I would need for each username to get and add the groups that is belonging to in the user-list.log. For example:

```
dante
Last password change                    : Aug 18, 2017
Password expires                    : never
Password inactive                   : never
Account expires                     : never
Minimum number of days between password change      : 0
Maximum number of days between password change      : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires   : 7
Linux shell                                         : /bin/bash
Groups                                              : dante, prime, trm

marion
Last password change                    : Aug 28, 2017
Password expires                    : never
Password inactive                   : never
Account expires                     : never
Minimum number of days between password change      : 0
Maximum number of days between password change      : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires   : 7
Linux shell                                         : /bin/bash 
Groups                                              : marion, secondary, krq
```

I need to run everything in one command and all quotes should be escaped because I will run it in Ansible. If is any other way to make it run in Ansible, I am opened to any suggestions.

Best regards,
Romain

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to run everything in one long and ugly command. With a little care you can run arbitrarily complex code, though I wouldn't get crazy with it.
Adjust this to your needs -

```
- name: run a complex shell command
  shell: |
    : careful with comments in here, and best to end lines with semicolons;
    while IFS=: read -r user x uid gid info home shell ;  
    do printf "\n$user\n";
       chage -l $user;
       printf "%-56s: $shell\n" "Linux shell"
       printf "%-56s: " "User Groups"
       grep $user /etc/group | cut -f 1 -d : | paste -s
    done < /etc/passwd > users-list.log
```

- or better yet, write and template a small script file and call it.

The `|` in `shell: |` means the following data is a single block scalar. Peek [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/in-yaml-how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines) for examples and elaborations, but it preserves lines. Just format your indentations carefully. :)

To add groups, you can parse the line according to [standard format](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/), but beware that the info field may or may not have data in it, and it can be somewhat arbitrary, likely embedding spaces.

Comment: Thank you, this was the way. I had many Linux distributions and for some of them works just if the last line is written like this: `done < /etc/passwd > users-list.log`